# How to detect application pool restart of a WCF service?

Tags: wcf

In my WCF service I use a static dictionary to hold some resource intensive data. I need to clean up the resources when the application pool gets recycled. Is there any method (for example event) by which I can detect that application pool is being recycled?

Answer (score 0):

if your application pool gets recycled all your static objects will be reset. you can clean all external resources (like files or ...) when creating an instance of your static dictionary. something like this:

```
public static partial class ProjectValues
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> MessageDictionary { private set; get; }


    static ProjectValues()
    {
        try
        {
            MessageDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
            //then clear the resource here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any method( for example event) by which I can detect that
>   application pool is being recycled?

Kinda.

According to [Phill Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/), IIS exposes a static method called [HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.registerobject.aspx), which allows you to pass implementations of IRegisteredObject into it.

In theory, this tells IIS to call the [IRegisteredObject.Stop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iregisteredobject.stop.aspx) operation before it decides to kill the w3wp.exe process your app is running in.

I say in theory because this approach is not fail-safe and there are instances where the AppDomain can go away without calling, or even to call but then shut down anyway, before you're finished doing your cleanup.